# Sublime text 3 file name tab font

Tags: sublimetext3

[image]

The file names on my system is unreadable. I have tried "tabset_control" but it didn't work. How do I change this font to something else?

Answer (score 2):

Open the .sublime-theme file for the theme you're using and then do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on Windows) for `tab_label`. There will probably be multiple instances, but look for one that contains `font.size` within the curly braces surrounding it. Add a line within those curly braces that says `"font.face": "Font Name",`(where "Font Name" is the name of a different font). If that line already exists you can just change the font name and then save the file. The tab font should change as soon as you save it.